# Should these kind of models be singleton? (Zend Framework)

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, models

In my project the classes called Object_X represents a single instance of X class (a row in a db table).

I also have to create models, to support these Object_X classes. For example: I think methods like "isEmailAddressTaken($email)" or "isLogged()" (for a customer db table for example) should go in a model (Model_Customer), is that right?

Now, if a class Object_X represents a row in the database and a Model_X represents the db table in general, should the Model_X be a singleton?

I'm kind of confused.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the task. zend framework has more features besides database access, which might help you.

Specifically, for any kind of validation, you should use `Zend_Validate` and create validators as you need. for example, for checking if an email is already taken, you should declare `Application_Validate_UserEmail_NotExists` which extends `Zend_Validate_Abstract`. then you will be able to use that vaildator class anywhere you need (especially in forms)

```
<?php

class Application_Validate_UserEmail_NotExists extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{   
    const REGISTERED_USER_EMAIL = 'invalid';
    const REGISTERED_USER_EMAIL_MESSAGE = 'Email already registered';

    protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::REGISTERED_USER_EMAIL => self::REGISTERED_USER_EMAIL_MESSAGE,
    );


    public function isValid($value)
    {   


        $modelUsers = new Model_Users();
        $user = $modelUsers->fetchRegisteredWithEmail($value);

        if (is_object($user)) {
            $this->isAlreadyRegisteredError = true;
            $this->_error(self::REGISTERED_USER_EMAIL);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}


$validator = new Application_Validate_UserEmail_NotExists();
if ($validator->isValid('email@domain.com')) {
    ....
}
```

for checking if the user is logged in, you should use `Zend_Auth`, which provides variety of functions to handle user authentication and session management.

Comment: First, thank you for answering. I already know about Zend_Validate and Zend_Auth, but for a customer for example, I would encapsulate Zend_Auth inside getLogged() and isLogged() methods. I think it's not good to call Zend_Auth directly in the controller, because I may need Zend_Auth not only for customers, but for other kind of authentication.

So, do you think it is valid to implement "fetchByEmail", "isLogged" and "getLogged" in the Model_Customer?